# Titanium web proxy cant load images

Tags: c#, proxy

I am working on a pen testing app written in c# and I am making use of Titanium proxy. I have been able to get html, css, js and other content types working. I am unable to get images to show though. Is there some secret to this?

The example code on the github for titanium has an if that only allows text/html through. Here is the code from the site, which I just added some else ifs to.

```
if (e.WebSession.Request.Method == "GET" || e.WebSession.Request.Method == "POST")
        {
            if (e.WebSession.Response.ResponseStatusCode == "200")
            {
                if (e.WebSession.Response.ContentType!=null && e.WebSession.Response.ContentType.Trim().ToLower().Contains("text/html"))
                {
                    byte[] bodyBytes = await e.GetResponseBody();
                    await e.SetResponseBody(bodyBytes);

                    string body = await e.GetResponseBodyAsString();
                    await e.SetResponseBodyString(body);
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried just adding an else, with the exact same code as the body of the above, to catch everything else but images never seem to load in the site although all CSS, JS and HTML seem to work fine.

Here is the link to Titanium web proxy github's page.
https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy

Answer (score 2):

```
e.WebSession.Response.ContentType.Trim().ToLower().Contains("text/html")
```

Images have differant content-type. You should remove above check and then use appropriate content-type. After that read the bytes and save it as an image using the format specified in content-type header.